# SystemVerilog Code for a lock combination (Finite State Machines)

Tags: verilog, xilinx, state-machines, system-verilog

I am writing code for a door lock combination. My inputs are b0, b1, b2 and b3, which correspond to the buttons to enter the code to unlock a door. The code to unlock this particular door is b2 --> b2 ---> b3 ---> b1.

However, between transitions,the code must take into account the user lifting their finger off the button before proceeding to press the next button for the door code.

ie. b2 --> release --> b2 --> release --> b2 --> release --> b3 ---> release --> any button ---> reset. 
If the user presses the wrong value in the process, the state must go back to the reset.

The picture below is my code, however, the synthesis is failing. I have looking through the next state logic of my code, but I can't seem to find any issue with it, and I am not getting any kind of syntax errors either.

I appreciate any help,
thank you for your time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zBji.png

```
 module Lock(input logic clk, reset, b0, b1, b2, b3,
 output logic unlock);

typedef enum logic[2:0] {s0, s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8} statetype;
statetype state, nextstate;



//state register
always_ff @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
    if (reset) state <= s0;
    else state<=nextstate; 

//next state logic    
always_comb
case (state)
s0: if (b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s1;
    else if (~(b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3))nextstate = s0;//ie. if did not press the corrrect button (b2)

s1: if (~b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s2; //. ie move a state ahead when you release the b2
    else if (b2 & ~b3 & ~b1 & ~b0) nextstate = s1; //ie. If user is holdig down the button b2.

s2: if (b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s3; //entering the second digit of the door code
 else if(~(  b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3))nextstate = s0; //back to reset if the second digit inserted is not b2
 else if  ( ~ b2 & ~b3 & ~b1 & ~b0) nextstate=s2;//e. if still havent pressed a button, stay in state s2

s3: if (~b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s4; // ie. when releasing button b2
     else if (b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s3;//ie. if holding down b2 still, stay in s3.

s4: if (b3 & ~b0 & ~b1 & ~b2) nextstate = s5;
   else if (~(b3 & ~b0 & ~b1 & ~b2))nextstate = s0;
    else if  ( ~ b2 & ~b3 & ~b1 & ~b0) nextstate=s4;

s5: if (~b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s6;
    else if (b3 & ~ b0 & ~ b1 & ~b2) nextstate=s5;

s6: if (b1 & ~b0 & ~b1 & ~b2 & ~b3) nextstate=s7;
    else if (~ (b1 & ~b0 & ~b1 & ~b2 & ~b3))nextstate=s0;
     else if  ( ~ b2 & ~b3 & ~b1 & ~b0) nextstate=s6;

s7: if (~b2 & ~b1 & ~b0 & ~b3) nextstate = s8;
    else if (b1 & ~b0 & ~b1 & ~b2 & ~b3) nextstate=s7;

s8: if (b0 + b1 + b2 + b3) nextstate = s0; //ie after unlocking, if press any button, return back to reset. 

endcase  

//output logic
assign unlock = (state==s7);

endmodule
```

Comment: PS. In the first case, S0, in the else if, the next state =S0, not S1. Apologies. I fixed that in my code, but it still is not synthesizing,

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than provide a screenshot. How do you know that "synthesis is failing"? If you are not getting syntax errors, are you getting any other errors or messages? Have you written a testbench and verified that your design works in simulation?

Comment: Hi. I  have run my testbench, and the error I am receiving is: value '3'b000' for enum 's8' already used by enum 's0'

Answer (score 0):

Your `logic` enum has 3 bits but there are 9 values in the enumeration. You need to provide more bits for `logic` or reduce the number of values in the enumeration.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the number of bits and it successfully synthesized. However, when I try to generate the bitstream, I just get an error saying that it can not generate it. Would this again have something to do with my code?

Comment: If it helps, the log is just showing me some peak and gain values.

Comment: As always, you need to provide the exact text of any error messages.